# Html file is not being rendered when I call erb program from After hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this small erb program,

```
def createHtml erbFileName,outputHtmlFile
  require 'erb'
  erb_str = File.read(erbFileName)
  @name = 'Generated by Ruby Automation Framework '
  renderer = ERB.new(erb_str)
  @result = renderer.result
  File.open(outputHtmlFile, 'w') do |f|
    f.write(@result)
  end
end
```

This program works fine when I call this function directly from the same file

```
createHtml 'ERBTemplate.html.erb','HTMLReport.html'
```

But I have to call this function from the Rspec `After hook`, When I call this same line from Rspec after hook, it's not rendering the value of `@name`. What might be the reason?

Look at the way I call the function below

```
describe 'Behavior' do
   it 'something' do
      puts 'something'
   end
   after(:all) do
    createHtml 'ERBTemplate.html.erb','HTMLReport.html'
   end
end
```

ERB Template look like this

```
<div id="footer">
  <% 5.times do %>
    <p><%= @name %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't have time to write a full fledged answer on the how's and why's of it, but the TLDR is you need to pass the binding of the method `@result = renderer.result binding` should fix it. Hopefully someone else can come along and expand upon that, if not I'll try and write a full answer here in the next few days on it

Comment: @SimpleLime That absolutely solves my problem. If you write an answer with little bit of explanation, I would accept the answer. Thanks.